# Returning DataSet from WCF to .Net Core application converts the DataSet to ArrayOfXElements type

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have my WCF service in .Net Framework that has a method of return type as DataSet, Now adding the WCF reference to .Net Core application converts the method's return type from DataSet to ArrayOfXElements while it's not converting the same for .net framework application.

Comment: You have not provided any useful information at all for us to help you.

Comment: what else useful information do you want?

Comment: edit your post and add sample code.